# What is the voltage range for GALAXY Tab 2 10.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I bought GALAXY Tab 2 10.1 from USA and going to use in Asia where I have 220V power. I am not sure if I can connect the power adapter that comes with the tab. There are no power specification mentioned there on the adapter or on the user manual.

Comment: What about in the adapter itself?

Comment: Nothing mentioned there.